# Multiplex between Iterators in TensorFlow

Tags: python, tensorflow

**What I need, functionally:** My dataset is partitioned in blocks, and each block sits in a binary file. 
I have an algorithm that also operates on blocks to reduce computational complexity, and then merges the results together, after visiting all blocks. It's important to have a single minibatch of data to originate from a single block, and to know which block exactly to be able to pass some parameters into the graph specific to that particular block. The next iteration, when starting again at block 0, the next minibatch from all blocks should be used. Blocks can have **non-equal lengths** and should be forever repeating.

**My current solution:** Currently, I create a `tf.Iterator` per block (i.e.: per file), created with a `tf.data.FixedLengthRecordDataset`:

```
// for every file:
ds = tf.dataFixedLengthRecordDataset(...)
ds = ds.repeat()
ds = ds.batch(...)
ds = ds.map(...)
ds = ds.prefetch(buffer_size=1)

it = ds.make_one_shot_iterator()
```

Then I have an "master" iterator that multiplexes between the file-level iterators. This is done through:

```
itr_handle = tf.placeholder(tf.string, shape=())
master_itr = tf.data.Iterator.from_string_handle(itr_handle, output_types)
master_next = master_itr.get_next()
```

So each time the graph is executed, I pass into the placeholder the string handle of the respective iterator I want to use for this execution. This way every file-level iterator still **has its own state**; so when the same block-file is asked for the next minibatch, it returns effectively the next minibatch, instead of reopening the file, and simply returning the first minibatch again.

**The problem:** Creating the file-level iterators is *slow*. It takes at least 200ms to create an Iterator per file. The dataset I use can easily contain up to 100 block-files, which causes TensorFlow/Python to be sitting there making these Iterator objects and graph nodes for 20 seconds, not actually processing any data.

**Question:**

1. Another approach to tackle this problem with only 1 iterator for example?
2. If not, how to speed up Iterator creation?

Comment: Looks like you can use the [tf.data](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/datasets) api, specifically [interleave](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/Dataset#interleave) or [parallel_interleave](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/contrib/data/parallel_interleave)
You would create a single dataset, interleaving data in according to the ordering you need, and then you batch it and have a single iterator iterate through it.

Comment: Do you need to explicitly control which block to pick a batch from on every graph run, or is this just something you added as part of your current solution?

Comment: @jdehesa: I want every block exactly once, then merge the results. Then I can repeat the whole process. While processing block by block, I need to know which block to configure the parameters in the algorithm, specific to that block.